# App Inventor Google fusiontables setup

Tags: google-fusion-tables, app-inventor

I have followed the Pizza Party tutorial (Hello World of App Inventor & fusion tables) and followed setup for service account access setup via following [instructions](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HifuZqz5xu0KPS-e4oUv-t-nQoUQ8VMNyh_y6OjZkc0/pub)

The problem I have is my app is not authorizing to write to the fusion table, i.e. [this is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jwvR.jpg)

[image]

So what I am trying to figure out is

1. from the developers console, are there log files I can see the authentication refused to validate the scree shot.
2. What are the troubleshooting steps to get the app writing to the fusion table.

Comment: forgot to add  i got error 2601:Fusion tables returned an error.  {query removed as it an auth error !....} The response was: 401 Unauthorized {"Error":"invalid_client","error_description","The OAuth client was not found."}

Comment: see here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/b4uP2GQTP7w/xqkRitvlBQAJ